# Alloy: use to String

Tags: string, passwords, alloy

How can I take the length of String in Alloy?

If I want to say that the password must have at least 8 character, how can I express the length of that string?

My signature of the password is:

sig Password{ password: one String }

Answer (score 1):

`String` in Alloy is pretty much like any other sig.  The only difference is that you can assign string literals to fields of type `String`, e.g.,

```
some p: Password | p.password = "secret"
```

No string functions are supported in Alloy.  Solving constraints like

```
some p: Password | len[p.password] > 5
```

would require a specialized string solver, which Alloy is not.

If you only care about password lengths, you could do something like

```
sig Char {}
sig Password { 
   password: seq Char 
} { 
   #password > 5
}
```

If you need to be able to solve more complicated string constraints (including regular expressions), you should look into specialized string solvers, e.g., [Hampi](http://people.csail.mit.edu/akiezun/hampi/).